# Extract Amzon ASIN from URL, RE, python

Tags: python, regex, url, web-scraping

I have a huge list of urls with links to Amazon products, this urls have an information contained within that I need that is called ASIN number.

I understand that one of the best ways to extract that information is via **Regular Expressions**, I found a pattern in the urls that could help

1- [https://www.amazon.com/adidas-Melange-Performance-T-Shirt-Charcoal/dp/B07P4LVZNL/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_2?dchild=1&keywords=Adidas+M%C3%A8lange+Tech+T-Shirt+A372&qid=1579685244&sr=8-2-fkmr1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P4LVZNL)

2- [https://www.amazon.com/adidas-Originals-Solid-Melange-Purple/dp/B07DXPN7TK/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_1?dchild=1&keywords=Adidas+M%C3%A8lange+Tech+T-Shirt+A372&qid=1579685244&sr=8-1-fkmr2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DXPN7TK)

3- https://www.amazon.com/adidas-Game-Mode-Polo-Multi-Sport/gp/B07R23QGH6/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_2?dchild=1&keywords=Adidas+M%C3%A8lange+Tech+T-Shirt+A372&qid=1579685244&sr=8-2-fkmr2

The respective ASIN numbers are:

1- **B07P4LVZNL**, located between: **dp/B07P4LVZNL/ref=sr_1_f**

2- **B07DXPN7TK**, located between: **dp/B07DXPN7TK/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_**

3- **B07R23QGH6**, located between: **gp/B07R23QGH6/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_**

I tried this code:

```
asin = re.match("http[s]?://www.amazon.com(\w+)(.*)/(dp|gp/product)/(?P<asin>\w+).*", href, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

href is the variable where I have stored the urls

But well... It doesn't work quite well, this is the type of result I get:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 175), match='https://www.amazon.com/adidas-Originals-Solid-Mel>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 171), match='https://www.amazon.com/adidas-Game-Mode-Polo-Mult>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 167), match='https://www.amazon.com/adidas-Tech-Tee-Black-X-La>
```

**Thank you for your help**

Comment: If you use the code you supplied, there [will be no matches](https://regex101.com/r/mfhvYU/1)

Comment: Maybe all you need is `re.findall(r'/[dg]p/([^/]+)', text)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using

```
/[dg]p/([^/]+)
```

It matches `/dp/` or `/gp/` and then captures into Group 1 any one or more characters other than `/`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T7ogta/1). In [Python](https://ideone.com/OZNhgz):

```
asin = re.search(r'/[dg]p/([^/]+)', href, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if asin:
  print(asin.group(1))
```

Comment: This one is very good! Worked for me.
I just changed a little detail to resume it:

`asin = re.search(r'/[dg]p/([^/]+)', href, flags=re.IGNORECASE).group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me -

```
re.search(r'B0[A-Z0-9]{8}', url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
match = re.search(r'%2Fdp%2F([^/]+)%2F', url)
```

Worked for me using re python.From an Amazon product URL with query parameters.